# Jsoup WhiteList to allow comments

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup 1.7.3 with `Whitelist` custom configuration.

Apparently it sanitizes all the HTML comments (`<!-- ... -->`) inside the document.

It also sanitizes the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` element.

1. How can I get jsoup `Whitelist` to allow comments as is?
2. How can I define the `!DOCTYPE` element as allowed element with any attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible by standard JSoup classes and its not dependent on WhiteList. Its the `org.jsoup.safety.Cleaner`. The cleaner uses a Node traverser that allows only elements and text nodes. Also only the body is parsed. So the head and doctype are ignored completely. So to achieve this you'll have to create a custom cleaner. For example if you have an html like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- This is a script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function newFun() {
            alert(1);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <map name="diagram_map">
            <area id="area1" />
            <area id="area2" />
        </map>
        <!-- This is another comment. -->
        <div>Test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You will first create a custom cleaner copying the orginal one. However please note the package should `org.jsoup.safety` as the cleaner uses some of the protected method of Whitelist associated with. Also there is not point in extending the Cleaner as almost all methods are private and the inner node traverser is final.

```
package org.jsoup.safety;

import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attribute;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Comment;
import org.jsoup.nodes.DataNode;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.DocumentType;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.parser.Tag;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeTraversor;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor;

public class CustomCleaner {
    private Whitelist whitelist;

    public CustomCleaner(Whitelist whitelist) {
    Validate.notNull(whitelist);
    this.whitelist = whitelist;
    }

    public Document clean(Document dirtyDocument) {
    Validate.notNull(dirtyDocument);

    Document clean = Document.createShell(dirtyDocument.baseUri());
    copyDocType(dirtyDocument, clean);
    if (dirtyDocument.head() != null) 
        copySafeNodes(dirtyDocument.head(), clean.head());
    if (dirtyDocument.body() != null) // frameset documents won't have a body. the clean doc will have empty body.
        copySafeNodes(dirtyDocument.body(), clean.body());

    return clean;
    }

    private void copyDocType(Document dirtyDocument, Document clean) {
    dirtyDocument.traverse(new NodeVisitor() {
        public void head(Node node, int depth) {
        if (node instanceof DocumentType) {
            clean.prependChild(node);
        }
        }
        public void tail(Node node, int depth) { }
    });
    }

    public boolean isValid(Document dirtyDocument) {
    Validate.notNull(dirtyDocument);

    Document clean = Document.createShell(dirtyDocument.baseUri());
    int numDiscarded = copySafeNodes(dirtyDocument.body(), clean.body());
    return numDiscarded == 0;
    }

    private final class CleaningVisitor implements NodeVisitor {
    private int numDiscarded = 0;
    private final Element root;
    private Element destination; // current element to append nodes to

    private CleaningVisitor(Element root, Element destination) {
        this.root = root;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void head(Node source, int depth) {
        if (source instanceof Element) {
        Element sourceEl = (Element) source;

        if (whitelist.isSafeTag(sourceEl.tagName())) { // safe, clone and copy safe attrs
            ElementMeta meta = createSafeElement(sourceEl);
            Element destChild = meta.el;
            destination.appendChild(destChild);

            numDiscarded += meta.numAttribsDiscarded;
            destination = destChild;
        } else if (source != root) { // not a safe tag, so don't add. don't count root against discarded.
            numDiscarded++;
        }
        } else if (source instanceof TextNode) {
        TextNode sourceText = (TextNode) source;
        TextNode destText = new TextNode(sourceText.getWholeText(), source.baseUri());
        destination.appendChild(destText);
        } else if (source instanceof Comment) {
        Comment sourceComment = (Comment) source;
        Comment destComment = new Comment(sourceComment.getData(), source.baseUri());
        destination.appendChild(destComment);
        } else if (source instanceof DataNode) {
        DataNode sourceData = (DataNode) source;
        DataNode destData = new DataNode(sourceData.getWholeData(), source.baseUri());
        destination.appendChild(destData);
        } else { // else, we don't care about comments, xml proc instructions, etc
        numDiscarded++;
        }
    }

    public void tail(Node source, int depth) {
        if (source instanceof Element && whitelist.isSafeTag(source.nodeName())) {
        destination = destination.parent(); // would have descended, so pop destination stack
        }
    }
    }

    private int copySafeNodes(Element source, Element dest) {
    CleaningVisitor cleaningVisitor = new CleaningVisitor(source, dest);
    NodeTraversor traversor = new NodeTraversor(cleaningVisitor);
    traversor.traverse(source);
    return cleaningVisitor.numDiscarded;
    }

    private ElementMeta createSafeElement(Element sourceEl) {
    String sourceTag = sourceEl.tagName();
    Attributes destAttrs = new Attributes();
    Element dest = new Element(Tag.valueOf(sourceTag), sourceEl.baseUri(), destAttrs);
    int numDiscarded = 0;

    Attributes sourceAttrs = sourceEl.attributes();
    for (Attribute sourceAttr : sourceAttrs) {
        if (whitelist.isSafeAttribute(sourceTag, sourceEl, sourceAttr))
        destAttrs.put(sourceAttr);
        else
        numDiscarded++;
    }
    Attributes enforcedAttrs = whitelist.getEnforcedAttributes(sourceTag);
    destAttrs.addAll(enforcedAttrs);

    return new ElementMeta(dest, numDiscarded);
    }

    private static class ElementMeta {
    Element el;
    int numAttribsDiscarded;

    ElementMeta(Element el, int numAttribsDiscarded) {
        this.el = el;
        this.numAttribsDiscarded = numAttribsDiscarded;
    }
    }

}
```

Once you have both you could do cleaning as normal. Like

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.safety.CustomCleaner;
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;

public class CustomJsoupSanitizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("t2.html"), "UTF-8");
            CustomCleaner cleaner = new CustomCleaner(Whitelist.relaxed().addTags("script"));
            Document doc2 = cleaner.clean(doc);
            System.out.println(doc2.html());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This will give you the sanitized output for above html as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <!-- This is a script --> 
  <script>
        function newFun() {
            alert(1);
        }
  </script> 
 </head>
 <body>     
  <!-- This is another comment. --> 
  <div>
   Test
  </div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

You can customize the cleaner to match your requirement. i.e to avoid head node or script tag etc...

Comment: That what I have been afraid off. Thanks. I wish the 'type of elements to be parsed' were also configurable.

Answer (score 0):

The Jsoup [Cleaner](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.7.3/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.java#Cleaner) doesn't give you a chance here (l. 100):

```
} else { // else, we don't care about comments, xml proc instructions, etc
    numDiscarded++;
}
```

Only instances of `Element` and `TextNode` may remain in the cleaned HTML.

Your only chance may be something horrible like parsing the document, replacing the comments and the doctype with a special whitelisted tag, cleaning the document and then parsing and replacing the special tags again.